# Validating Parameterized Std Deviation Estimator

Tags: estimators

I'm looking to estimate the size of the intersection between two sets, $A$ & $B$

I have a function to estimate this ($\verb|est_set_intersect_size|(A, B)$) that purports to have a standard deviation of the error between real and estimated intersection sizes as

$$
\sigma_{err} = \sqrt{\frac{size(A \cup B)}{size(A \cap B)}} C
$$
(Note: $C$ is a predetermined constant)

I can generate a sample of example sets and the exact size of their intersections, as well as their estimated size.

My question is how do I validate $\verb|est_set_intersect_size|(A, B)$ and the provided std dev estimator as accurate given that the latter is parameterized by aspects of sets $A$ & $B$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you please explain the sense in which you need to *estimate* the intersection?  Ordinarily, one just counts the number of elements in both sets.  Evidently you can't do that, but exactly what information do you have about the sets?

Comment: The sets are too large to calculate the exact size of their intersections quickly. I can estimate the size of each individual set as well as the size of their union, all with a std dev of the error as equal to the constant C. It's a strange approach in which you don't have the actual set, but can estimate it's size by itself or when set operations are performed on it. Normally, the std dev of err is constant when you do this, but estimating the size of a set intersection is a special case, and I'm looking to validate the std dev of err this approach puts forward.

Comment: If you want to get really in the weeds, I'm using theta sketches https://datasketches.apache.org/docs/Theta/ThetaSketchSetOpsAccuracy.html and looking to validate their claims.

Comment: I looked briefly at those docs, but they read too much like propaganda and do not readily disclose what they are actually doing.